# What are gem forges used for?

Tags: infinity-blade-2

I realized that in Infinity Blade 2, if I combine gems of the same kind, I get one super powerful gem, the price of which exceeds the price of its component gems.

I wonder what other uses of gem forges are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make *only* make [square](http://infinityblade.wikia.com/wiki/Square_Gem) or [circle](http://infinityblade.wikia.com/wiki/Circle_Gem) gems go above +400 of their given stat at a gem forge by combining 3 similar gems that are all +400(stat).

There are also [certain rare gems](http://infinityblade.wikia.com/wiki/Gem_Forge#Other_Recipes) that can be crafted at the gem forge.

I'm trying to find info on this but I think if all combined gems are the same shape, the resulting gem is also that shape. Similarly, if all gems give the same stat then the resulting gem is a stronger version of that stat also.