# Gem forging - Infinity Blade 3

Tags: infinity-blade-3

I'm wondering if someone knows the answer to more specifics of gem-forging than what's on wiki's:

- Can I for square gems of all types and still get a square gem? Let's say 2 of them are wind attack, and other Damage Titan on slash.
- If I forge 1 capped gem (+400 dark) and 2 basic ones (+1 dark, +85 light) will I get 400+ gem or a worse gem in the end?

Comment: I Asked a [similar question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/135390/is-there-any-way-to-predict-the-outcome-of-a-gem-fuse) a while ago with no answer. I guess nobody truly know

Comment: IIRC the only way to get gems above their "cap" is to forge 3 similar "capped" gems together. Such as forging 3 +400 matching element gems together will give a +500 gem. same with +200 matching stat gems. I answered a [similar question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/101983/37612) for IB2 which should still be true here

Answer (score 1):

Had to test myself:

Fusing gems of the same type but different stats will result in gem of the original shape but random stats.

Fusing strong gem with weaker gems results in a better gem, but stats are increased only a little. A +40 dark damage and +2 wind, +5 poison gems resulted in +47 light gem.